# 2-Buttons merged. Not able to select the first one in JAVA & SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium, button, xpath, webdriver

I'm working with a multi-language page and i got a button called **Upload File**

[image]

I tried to click on that button using Selenium and JAVA but not matter what it cannot be clicked:

That button has this:

```
<div class="row attachment-files-item" style="display: none;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link add-row">Upload File</button>
</div>
```

The XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="documentation"]/div/div[2]/div/button
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"documentation\"]/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();
```

It is not working, i cannot reach to the second button.

What am i doing wrong?

---

EDIT#1:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row attachment-files-item" style="display: none;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link add-row">Upload File</button>
</div>
```

If you see the parent element of the button, Its style `style="display: none;` means it is hidden on the page.
You need to change the style to `style="display: block;` to unhide this.

use javascript executor to set the attribute.

```
ele =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row attachment-files-item']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:block;')", ele);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row attachment-files-item']//button[text()='Upload File']")).click();
```

please add delay while interacting either implicit or explicit.

Comment: Hey pal, thank you for replying!. It says: "ele cannot be resolved to a variable", what data type should i use?

Comment: Take a look, i have edited my question. I did this:
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row attachment-files-item']"));
 driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:block')", ele);

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row attachment-files-item']//button[text()='Upload File']")).click();

But it says: The method executeScript(String, WebElement) is undefined for the type WebDriver

Comment: Sorry missed the `;`

Comment: @new_programmer : can you check now. I have updated the `;` which I have missed.

Comment: It throws the same error message

Comment: @new_programmer : Sorry pal, can you check now?

Comment: Hey i put this: WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row attachment-files-item']"));

Comment: Webelement ele, is that okay for you?